# python + unicodeEncodeError \xb5 while reading from excel and writing to msqldatabase

Tags: python-2.7, python-unicode

I have a python 2.7 script that reads data from an excel file where it is possible that the user uses special characters (e.g. µ). and write it in a msqldatabase.

I've added the next code on top f the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But it still uses the ascii codec. How can I solve this error.

This is the errocode:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb5' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

tx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue while inserting values from 3rd party app. over there I used to insert values with escape string.

```
from re import escape
r = escape('µ')
```

Result:

```
'\\\xc2\\\xb5'
```

in insert statement pass r variable value.

Comment: Tx for the idea, I'm going to try it out.